# C# object cannot be cast from dbnull to other types

Tags: c#, object, datagridview, casting, dbnull

I am getting this exception at datagridview CellFormatting event.
All I am doing in this event is changing cell style based on datagridview cell values. How can I get this error in such operations? Can anyone help me?
The event method is given below:

```
private void datagridPM_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (datagridPM.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[datagridPM.ColumnCount - 1].Value.ToString() == "RUNNING")
            {
                datagridPM.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[datagridPM.ColumnCount - 1].Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle { ForeColor = Color.Green, BackColor = Color.White };
                if (e.RowIndex == current_selected.RowIndex)
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => strt_btn.Text = "STOP"));


            }
            else if (datagridPM.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[datagridPM.ColumnCount - 1].Value.ToString() == "STOPPED")
            {
                datagridPM.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[datagridPM.ColumnCount - 1].Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle { ForeColor = Color.Red, BackColor = Color.White };
                if (e.RowIndex == current_selected.RowIndex)
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => strt_btn.Text = "START"));
            }               

            datagridPM.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font(DataGridView.DefaultFont, FontStyle.Bold);
            datagridPM.Columns[datagridPM.ColumnCount - 1].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font(DataGridView.DefaultFont, FontStyle.Bold);

            if (Convert.ToDouble(datagridPM.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[datagridPM.ColumnCount - 6].Value)>80.00)
            {

                datagridPM.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[datagridPM.ColumnCount - 6].Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle { ForeColor = Color.Red, BackColor = Color.Wheat };

            }
            else
            {
                datagridPM.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[datagridPM.ColumnCount - 6].Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle { ForeColor = Color.Black, BackColor = Color.White };

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MDIParent.thisMdiObj.Invoke(new Action(() => MDIParent.thisMdiObj.txtLog.AppendText(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " : " + "CELL FORMATTING EXCEPTION : " + ex.Message.ToString() + "::" + ex.StackTrace + Environment.NewLine)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should include the full exception and stack trace you're getting.

Comment: I didnot get this exception on VS2010. I got it when it was run as an application. So I could not figure out from where the exception is arising. All I got was the message 'object cannot be cast from dbnull to other types'.

Comment: Then can you run it via Visual Studio and post more information?

Comment: The first thing you should do in this function is checking `if (datagridPM.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[datagridPM.ColumnCount - 1].Value == null` or nullptr or dbnull, whatever is needed. Otherwise you might execute the ToString() function on a not existing object, which of course would cause an exception. BTW: Didn't you get the line numbers of your exception? For future purposes you could also do a try-catch around the Application.Run and additionally add an UnhandledException event handler to catch exceptions you may get from different threads.

Comment: So you are basically asking me to do the entire operation of the event after checking whether the current cell value is not null or dbnull or nullptr? 
I didnt tried that.I think I should try it once. Plus, I one got the line number from the stack trace that was too on the first line where am checking

`if (datagridPM.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[datagridPM.ColumnCount - 1].Value.ToString() == "RUNNING")`